# ValidationProvider isn't displaying the error message of the dictionary - VeeValidate with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vee-validate

I would like to customize the error message of a **component** that didn't match the **"cpf"** rule. For that kind of situation, I think that the dictionary of custom messages should work, but I couldn't figure it out how to implement this.

This [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8nj3363zn0?from-embed) **works for a simple input**, but I would like to **validate a component**

So far, to display the error message **"Favor preencher o cpf"** from the `dict`, I've made [that example](https://codesandbox.io/s/m35068ol4x), but the error message isn't displaying.

A working CodeSandBox example would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CodeSandBox example works https://codesandbox.io/s/5xo48x1qkp